# What's the slug size limit of Heroku Hobby Plan?

Tags: java, jsp, heroku

I tried to push my JSP website to Heroku which failed because of the slug size, so would it help if I upgrade to their Hobby Plan.

that's the log msg:

!     Compiled slug size: 855.8M is too large (max is 500M).

!     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size

!     Push failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slug size is the same across all plans, 500Mb. That article will refer to .slugignore as a means to reduce slug size which may help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to reduce the slug size of Java application in the Dev Center article on [Reducing the Slug Size of Java Applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/reducing-the-slug-size-of-java-applications).